# Biopython installation on MacOSX El Capitan, gcc error -Qunused-arguments

Tags: macos, biopython

I am trying to install Biopython, but get this error:

```
> gdr$ python setup.py build running build running build_py running
> build_ext building 'Bio.cpairwise2' extension gcc -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv
> -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Qunused-arguments -Qunused-arguments -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.7.2.3327.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7
> -c Bio/cpairwise2module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/Bio/cpairwise2module.o gcc: error:
> unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’ gcc: error:
> unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’ error: command
> 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am running a MacOSX El Capitan 10.11.3, with gcc version 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease). 
It seems no else reported this problem neither here on stackoverflow nor on google (made a quick search).

**(update) SOLUTION:**

I solved editing the `os_clang_fix()` in the `setup.py` installation file, commenting:

```
#    for flag in ["CFLAGS", "CPPFLAGS"]:
#        if flag not in os.environ:
#            os.environ[flag] = "-Qunused-arguments"
#        elif "-Qunused-arguments" not in os.environ[flag]:
#            os.environ[flag] += " -Qunused-arguments"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a `clang` specific option, and, as far as I know, it's unavailable in `gcc`.

From `clang` manpage:

> ```
>    -Qunused-arguments
>        Don't emit warning for unused driver arguments.
> ```

You have [at least] two options to solve that:

- Remove any ocurrences of `Qunused-arguments` around the project build files (I don't really recommend this one).
- Install `clang` (just run `clang` on the terminal and follow the installation instructions).

Also [personal opinion ahead], if you don't need `gcc` for any particular reason, uninstall it, and keep `clang` on your OSX as it seems to be Apple's wishes :).

Comment: Good piece of advice: it got me on the right track. Thank you pah :).